# How to read values from a CSV file with fgets() without skipping data?

Tags: c, csv, fopen, strtok, getc

I'm trying to read a CSV file where I have just double values separated with a comma. I'm using the `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)` function to read the rows. In the code, to finish the do-while loop, I'm using the `getc()` method to read the next char, to find out if I've read the end of the file. The problem is, `getc()` method read the first character from the next line, so I'm losing data (as the first number in the next line loses one digit). As you can see, apart from the first row, all the first column entries lost their first characters.

What should I use to control my while loop? Or is there another method that I should use to read data from CSV files? Thank you very much

**Data from my_file.csv:**

3.0000,4.0000,5.0000,6.0000,7.0000
6.0000,5.0000,4.0000,3.0000,2.0000
9.0000,6.0000,3.0000,0.0000,-3.0000
12.0000,7.0000,2.0000,-3.0000,-8.0000
15.0000,8.0000,1.0000,-6.0000,-13.0000
18.0000,9.0000,0.0000,-9.0000,-18.0000

**Actual output:**

[enter image description here][1]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void getData(char *buff);

int main() {

    char folder_addr[] = "C:\\my_file.csv";

    FILE *fp = fopen(folder_addr, "r");
    do  {
        char buff[1024];
        fgets(buff, 1024, (FILE*)fp);
        printf(buff);
        getData(buff);
    } while ((getc(fp)) != EOF);

    return 0;
};

void getData(char *buff){
    char *token = strtok(buff, ",");
    //printf("First value:  %s\n", token);

    while (token != NULL)   {
        //printf("First value:  %s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQzw1.jpg
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `ungetc()`?

Comment: Or better yet, since it fixes multiple issues, just check what `fgets()` returns instead of assuming it works.

Comment: Also `printf(buff);` should be `fputs(buff, stdout);` to prevent issues with undefined behavior if `buff` has % characters in it.

Comment: `fgets(..., (FILE*)fp)` --- `fp` is a value of `FILE*` type. The explicit conversion is unnecessary, redundant, and confusing.

Comment: You know how many columns csv file has. Why do you not using fscanf?

Comment: Do you ever have multi-line character fields in your CSV data?  If so, how are newlines handled?  Just an extra complication which you probably don't need to worry about for your exercise.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In this problem I won't be having any multi-line character fields, every entry will be just double values, but that is an interesting problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is to just do a `while(fgets())` instead of a do-while. I would not say that peeking a single char is the best method here.

For those cases where it is a reasonable option (if such a case exists) to do so, you can do a `fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR)` to go back one step. It is a tiny bit ugly, but not to bad and it gets the job done. You would need to reorder a little bit like this:

```
while ((getc(fp)) != EOF) {
    fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
    char buff[1024];
    fgets(buff, 1024, (FILE*)fp);
    printf(buff);
    getData(buff);
}
```

However, do note that the `fseek` is not guaranteed to work if the stream is not seekable, such as pipes. It is better to use `ungetc`. Same principle. You put the character you just read back in the stream.

A similar method is this:

```
int c;
while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
    char buff[1024];
    buff[0]=c;
    fgets(&buff[1], 1023, (FILE*)fp);
    printf(buff);
    getData(buff);
}
```

You should also change `printf(buff)` to `puts(buff)`

Comment: I've checked the `fseek()` method and it works! Also, changing the order of the `do-while` loop to a `while(fgets())` gets to work done! Thank you very much!

Comment: BTW, in the second method that you suggested, why is the type of `c` is `int` and not `char` ? I've tried and both of them works but I'm not sure why...

Comment: `getc` returns an int. The reason for that is that getc may return EOF, which does not fit in a char.

Comment: Whenever getc does not return EOF, you can safely assign a char variable to the value of `c`

Comment: It isn't clear that the `fseek()` method is guaranteed to work with non-seekable devices (such as terminals and pipes).  It would be better — guaranteed to work by the C standard — to use `ungetc()` to put back the character that was read (as long as a character was read — as long as you didn't get EOF).

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `do {fgets()...} while(getc);` with `while (fgets()) {...}`